# What is sustaining software engineering?

Tags: agile, sdlc

I've come across the phrase 'sustaining software engineering' but don't know exactly what it means. There seems to be some DoD connection? Is it related to Agile Development?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe "sustaining" is another word for "maintenance": it's what happens after software is released, i.e. support, bug fixing, enhancements ...

Comment: This is how the term is used where I work.

Comment: Although correct, some elaboration would be better. Specially on the part of enhancements.

Answer (score 20):

Many in the software world define sustaining engineering as the bug fix team. While this is a part of the duties involved the sustaining engineering group should also be looking at the overall defect trends to help identify areas needing re-factoring. The focus of the group should be to not just fix bugs as they come in but to be the conduit back into engineering to ELIMINATE needless calls from customers. That might involve "works as designed" issues as well as product areas the customers just have a hard time understanding.

Comment: This should be merged with the "accepted" answer. I did but someone deleted the change...

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 7):

[Sustainable Software Engineering](http://www.scribd.com/doc/5507536/Sustainable-Software-Engineering): Consideration of the social and environmental effects of software projects in managing the project. Managing a software project in order to maximize the positive and minimize the negative social and environmental effects of the project.

Alternative (Sustaining): Consideration of the long-term support requirements during the design and development of a software project.  The process of conducting the long-term support required when development is complete.

Answer (score 3):

It's just a fancy way of saying "Software Maintenance Team".

Answer (score 1):

Sustaining Software Engineering, at least in the cases where I've come across it, is the department responsible for implementing hot-fixes for released products, and handling customer service issues that the tech-support guys can't resolve on their own.